# Do I have to do something after 25 years of not being able to make a payment to get forgiveness

Tags: loans

My first loan was in 1979 and I have never had enough income to be required to make a payment (despite a Masters in Computer Science). I believe I have always been on some sort of income based plan. According to the Student Loan website loans are forgiven after 25 years on the income-based plans. Should I have been forgiven by now? Do I have to do something? Is there a way to find out how many years I have left? Does the clock start over if someone switches your income-based plan to a different one (there are several similar plans)?

Mohela, my current provider, said they don't have access to records of my loan before it got transferred to them from Aspire in 2015 (after the phone person spent some time 'digging them up'). The Government Student Loan site does not appear to have any way to contact them on this or anything else, there is just a link to determine who is handling your loan, Mohela in my case. I remember my loan being given to Aspire from the government around 10 years ago, but I'm not sure on this. They were all taken out over the years with the Federal government, no banks were involved. My loan total is now about $110,000.

The best response I got from Mohela was that I would get an email notification (from the Government?) when the 25 years was up, but as I mentioned earlier, my first loan was taken out in 1979, 37 years ago. My last loan was taken out sometime in the 80s. I think the phone person was just putting me off on this.

Mohela still gives me monthly billing statements saying I owe $0.00 payment each month and each year I forward them my fed tax returns (which I always do despite not owing taxes) for my payment calcuation,

Comment: It sounds like you may have acknowledged the loan. If so, in most jurisdictions, that resets the timer.

Comment: What do you mean by 'acknowledged the loan'.

Comment: You acknowledged that you had a loan. That means that whatever legalities that would have allowed it to slip off, no longer apply. For example, in some places, if you don't make a payment for a certain period of time, then the statute of limitations allows it to, in essence, disappear. For example, if the statute of limitations is 7 years, and you don't make a payment for those 7 years (even though it is still affecting your credit score), then it will disappear. However, if you contact them, or make even a $0.01 payment on it the day before the 7 years are up, it resets the clock.

Comment: You said income plan...is this a student loan? And was it  federal or private? Laws differ tremendously based on such factors.

Comment: @Zymus acknowledging the loan has nothing to do with forgiveness

Comment: Federal student loan from government,

Comment: Given the loan amount and the time that's passed, I'd say you should speak with an attorney. There are usually programs for low income individuals to get free legal advice. Try searching for such programs in your area. Law schools sometimes have law students put on legal clinics for low income individuals as well. It might be worth contacting local law schools to see if they do legal clinics.

Comment: I haven't tried law schools, but have tried everything else as far as free legal advice. I've always been told by legal aid and others that they don't handle my issue. I had one tell me it would be tough for me as there is no money to be made for the attorney and no attorney would have experience with my issue. In fact he thought my issue was unique.

Answer (score 1):

After all this time, I'd suggest pulling a credit report to see if the loan even shows up. If it's there, that means they are still reporting it, and they should have been able to give you details about it.